# Why I can't add property to winston types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I create `custom-typings.d.ts` in my project and I just want to add property to the [`Logger` interface](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/index.d.ts#L87).

In my `custom-typings.d.ts` I add my something property:

```
declare namespace winston {
    interface Logger {
        something: string;
    }    
}
```

When I type: `const { something } = logger.info('blabla');`

The error I get is `Property 'something' does not exist on type 'Logger'.`

(in javascript I override the return `__proto__` type with that field)

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your `tsconfig.json` file to [look for your types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)?

**UPDATE**
Your problem is the way you declare the types. 
This is how you `.d.ts` file should look like:

```
export {};
declare module "winston" {
  interface Logger {
    something: string;
  }
}
```

Do note that the first line `export {};` is imperative, so that the file will be treated as a module. And the second change is that you re-declare the module "winston", rather than the namespace.

Comment: This is not enough. you need to add `import winston from 'winston';` for not lose `winston` types.

Comment: I got it working even without this line. You can take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sea-mhyqp?fontsize=14) example.